# Wait for a month to change my display name

Tags: support, users, rate-limiting, display-names

Why do I have to wait for a month to change my display name?

I mistakenly got the spelling of my name wrong so wanted to change it.

Comment: Because you recently changed it and you are not allowed to do this all the time.

Comment: Question for you - why would you need to change it more often? Or rather - even **that** often?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like all things on Stack Overflow, changing your display name is rate limited. This is done to prevent undue confusion and trolling. People here do try to communicate with you (in answers, comments, etc.) and constantly changing usernames make it very hard to keep track of whom one is talking to.

If your account is less than 2 days old, you can change your name at will (to give you a chance to settle on one).

If you do change your name, you have a 15 minute window in which to change it again, but after that 15 minute window you are stuck with that name for at least 30 days.

See [Can we restrict the ability of users to keep changing their names?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. I didn't knew I can undo name in 15 minutes. Mistakenly name of my spelling got wrong so wanted to change it

Comment: @Raakesh: it is that kind of detail that can make a difference in any question; *why* you are asking. I've added it to your post.