# Who can track display name changes?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

Is it possible to see the history of all the display names of a specific user?

If a regular user can't, who can? Or how much reputation do I need to see such data?

Comment: I'm not sure if a history is kept at all for name changes? Any particular reason why you want to know that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - When someone changes their display name, old comments that were addressed to them no longer appear to make sense - if I changed my name to `SpaceMonkeys`, comments addressed to `@GalacticCowboy` would no longer appear to be addressed to me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Users can see their *own* most recent display names (but only if they were different *enough*; changing a few characters won't add to this list); you'll find the list by the *Display name* box when editing your profile:

> [image: Link to recent names]

Click on the number and you get:

> [image: Recent names dialog box]

Names stay in that list for 90 days. This list is private, so ordinary users cannot see this list for anyone but themselves.

Diamond Moderators (and Stack Overflow developers) can see *all* display 
name changes in the user history, for any user.

Now, before everyone runs off to go change their display name to see this feature in action, take into account that [changing your display name is rate limited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261765/wait-for-a-month-to-change-my-display-name), so you can easily get stuck with the new display name for the next 30 days.

Comment: Now I'm tempted to change my display name to Zopatista...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: *Zopatista* is my personal company name, as well as my .com domain name. It is a play on *Zapatista* and the Python web platform *Zope*. You are free to use it as a display name here on Stack Overflow, but don't be surprised if people come and ask you obscure Zope or Plone questions.

Comment: I would have loved to see the ridiculous names that people would have been stuck with for a month, had they not been warned about the rate-limiting.

Comment: @Louis for that, Martijn could remove the warning and instead promise right here that he will fix all the names that readers of this post would try (using his mod powers) and right after that, go off-line for a month (IIRC there were complaints at elections that he was offline in January 2013 or 2012, he could do it again)

Comment: @gnat: that was a [brief dip in December 2013](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289995/2015-moderator-candidate-activity-profiles#comment175556_289995) (the graph tracks weeks, I think, so it was not a whole month). :-P

Answer (score 28):

Using the Stack Exchange API, it's possible to find most of a user's past display names, provided they were sufficiently active under those names to receive some comments addressed to them in the @username format.

See [Find old display names of a user](https://stackapps.com/q/6276) on Stack Apps.

Comment: I've bookmarked this and come back to it three times already since yesterday. I foresee a very profitable relationship! ;)

Comment: That thing shows a *lot* of false positives. I've never changed my display name (except when I set it to something initially beside the default), but it found 9 "display names" for me. 5 were typos; the rest had nothing to do with me.