# How do I rename my user name (display name)?

Tags: support, display-names

I can't find it... could it be that I am blocked from changing my user name because I changed a couple of times before?

I think right now, if I put Chinese characters in my user name, some people are very irritated because maybe they don't know what those characters mean or how to pronounce it.

Comment: If you change your username, you need to wait [one month](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261765/wait-for-a-month-to-change-my-display-name?rq=1) before changing it again.